# How to get the GitLab userid in a Python app that uses GitLab as an Oauth provider?

Tags: oauth, gitlab-api

I'm writing a Python app that uses GitLab as OAuth provider. When an user logs in in the app (which redirects to GitLab login), the app receives an oauth token.

Using the GitLab API in Python, how can my app get the current GitLab userid?

I've tried something like this:

```
import gitlab

# create a GitLab API client
gitlab_url = 'https://your.gitlab.url/api/v4'
auth_token = 'your-auth-token-here'
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(gitlab_url, private_token=auth_token)

# get the current user's information and the user id
user_id = gl.user.id

print(f'The user ID is {user_id}')
```

but `gl.user` is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing `private_token` by `oauth_token`, then calling `gl.auth()`:

```
import gitlab

# create a GitLab API client
gitlab_url = 'https://your.gitlab.url/api/v4'
auth_token = 'your-auth-token-here'
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(gitlab_url, oauth_token=auth_token)
gl.auth()

# get the current user's information and the user id
user_id = gl.user.id

print(f'The user ID is {user_id}')
```